# What does it mean to find a location of a singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

For example: I am asked to find the singularities (their location and types) for the function $f(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2\cos^2(z/2)}{(z+1)^3z(z-\pi)}$.
I found a pole of order 3 at $z=-1$, a pole of order 1 at $z=0$, and a removable singularity at $z=\pi$ using Taylor Series expansion.

I am confused what the location is though. Is it just the $z=$# value?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks. I just wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, location just means the $z$-value where there is a singularity. Viewing complex numbers as points in the complex plane motivates this.